# How can I select the most recent input for each member?

Tags: mysql

Assume I have a MySQL table:

```
╔══════╦═════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ time ║ mid ║ field_1 ║ field_2 ║
╠══════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  100 ║   1 ║      32 ║      54 ║
║  100 ║   2 ║       0 ║      34 ║
║  100 ║   3 ║      44 ║      99 ║
║  200 ║   1 ║       0 ║      45 ║
║  200 ║   2 ║       0 ║      45 ║
║  200 ║   3 ║       4 ║      59 ║
║  200 ║   4 ║      45 ║      45 ║
╚══════╩═════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

time is a UNIX timestamp. mid is the member id. field_1 is supplied by the member. field_2 is filled automatically.

I wish to select the row with the most recent non-zero field_1 for all members. So the query would result in:

```
╔══════╦═════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ time ║ mid ║ field_1 ║ field_2 ║
╠══════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  100 ║   1 ║      32 ║      54 ║
║  200 ║   3 ║       4 ║      59 ║
║  200 ║   4 ║      45 ║      45 ║
╚══════╩═════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

The only solution I came up with does not seem very elegant:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM t1
    WHERE field_1 > 0
    ORDER BY time DESC
) AS a
GROUP BY mid
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Try to learn about [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM t1 AS a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT mid, MAX(time) AS maxTime
    FROM t1
    WHERE field_1 <> 0
    GROUP BY mid
) b ON a.mid = b.mid AND a.time = b.maxTime
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/798d9/1)

Answer (score 4):

The idea here is to create a subquery which gets the max `time` for each `mid` and join it on the table itself.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT mid, MAX(time) maxV
FROM tableName
WHERE field_1 > 0
GROUP BY mid
) b ON a.mid = b.mid and
        a.time = b.maxV
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6af44/9)